# World Record Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, pi-b+

Has anyone set any Guinness World Records related to the Raspberry Pi, like longest time a Raspberry Pi has been continually powered for?

Comment: I don't see how any claims could be verified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, there are no Guinness World Records related to the Raspberry Pi. There are a few about Linux in general, but I was unable to find anything that contained *raspberry pi* or *raspbian*.

Search for yourself: http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/search

Comment: What about this post? (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/babbages-big-jump-the-aftermath/)

Comment: @dylan: interesting, but none of them are acknowledged by Guinness.

Comment: Where the google fu gets tricky for this answer is that it's conceivable that there's a record for something like 'world's fastest conveyor belt' that incorporates a pi which goes unmentioned in the record description. The descriptions don't seem to dip much into implementation details.

Comment: What if one of my Pis was powered from day 1 but failed after 3 years even though it is still powered.

Comment: @goobering: That's true, but I would still expect it to be easy to find things *related to the RPi* as in "longest uptime" on an RPi if it existed.

Comment: @joan: If you get a plaque from Guinness, I'll be happy to update the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Now that a few years have past, there are some!

Most Notable:

-Most Pis used in parallel

-Fastest Raspberry Pi

-Sending a teddy bear to space using a microcontroller (Highest Altitude)

[image: Screenshot of assorted records]

Check out the live update here: https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/search?term=raspberry%20pi&page=1&type=record&max=20&partial=_Results&